# Rotate through the contents of multiple text files in one single file?

Tags: python

I have 2 text files that will automatically update thanks to an external program. These two text files will contain a name. I want to have a third text file that displays the contents of the other texts files on rotation (one text file shows at one time - then it automatically reads the 2nd file and replaces the current text - then back to the first etc). I am not a programmer but would massively appreciate anyone who can help me with this.

I've tried to follow at first some java script tutorials so that i could display the names on rotation in a HTML document but I found you needed to select the text files manually. I then also tried some python tutorials but I am in way over my head.

```
    def main():
        with open("textfile1.txt") as f:
            with open("file3.txt", "w") as f1:
                for line in f:
                    if "" in line:
                        f1.write(line)
main()
```

This works to put the text from the first file into the 3rd file. How can I make it alternate on a timer? So after 30 secs the text in the 3rd file changes from the 1st files contents to the 2nd files contents and then back again after 30 secs?

Comment: Nothing happens because you never called the `main()` function. Python doesn't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you run the main function in your script?
If not, then run it. After function write 'main()' (without quotes). 
All code:

```
def main():
    with open("textfile1.txt") as f:
        with open("file3.txt", "w") as f1:
            for line in f:
                if "" in line:
                    f1.write(line)

main()
```

Comment: Someone other programming languages are automatically call the main function, but not Python

Comment: sorry, my inexperience there. It now works for putting the names from one file into the new file. But i'm wondering how to make it alternate between the two text files now - on a timer of some sort?

Comment: From first text file to second text file and vice versa - from second text file to first? I understood correctly?

Comment: You can make it the same as the original version, but you must swap the name files in first and second 'with'. And thats all. If you make a timer, you'll don't have a correctly result. Timers are wait a some time and run the function. If you want to wait some time before write a data from second file to first - create two functions for write data in various files, after running the first function create a timer: 
t = Timer(30.0, second_func)
t.start()
Where 30.0 - seconds to run the func, second_func - name of function. It's must be without the manual running the second_func.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it. You need the [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time) module to set a time interval during the alternation.

```
import time

def replacetext(sourcefile, destinationfile):
    with open(sourcefile) as sf:
        with open(destinationfile, "w") as df:
            for line in sf:
                df.write(line)
                print(line)


origfiles = ['textfile1.txt', 'textfile2.txt'] #list of source files
destfile = 'file3.txt' #the destination file
delay = 5 #the time interval (in seconds) from one writing to another

while True:
    for ff in origfiles:
        replacetext(ff, destfile)
        time.sleep(delay) #delay in seconds
```

I renamed your main function `replacetext`, but it does the same thing. Only difference, it takes the filenames as arguments.

Pay attention that this is an infinite loop. It will never stop until you interrupt the script from command line.
To make it stop after a given number of alternation, you need to add a counter. For example:

```
counter = 0
while counter < 10:
    counter += 1
    for ff in origfiles:
        replacetext(ff, destfile)
        time.sleep(delay) #the program sleeps for "delay" seconds
```

In this case the program terminates after 10 iteration.

Comment: how could I add a stop button? so it will run infinitely until the stop button is pressed?

Comment: Buttons make me think to a GUI. Do you already have a GUI for your program? Because creating a GUI is a whole task by itself, beyond the scope of your question.